# Pandas Concat - not permanent / in place?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I wrote a small function to add 1 row to the end of a given DF. In my jupyter notebook file, the output window adds 1 row, and all appears to work perfectly as expected.

```
def add_row(df):

    df_temp_row = pd.DataFrame({'time':[np.nan], 'mid_o':[np.nan], 'mid_h':[np.nan], 'mid_l':[np.nan], 'mid_c':[np.nan]})
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp_row], ignore_index=True, axis=0, copy=True)

    return df
```

However, when I check the df `len(df.index)` the result is 1 less row than expected, as if the function failed.

It seems odd. Any advice please?

Comment: You need to *re-assign* your dataframe, `df = add_row(df)`, then `len(df.index)` will return 2.

Comment: School boy error! Thank you @Timeless

Comment: @user3316115. You can also append a row with `df.loc[len(df)] = np.nan`. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well if you think to override the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
print('Original length:', len(df))
df = add_row(df)  # <- don't forget to reassign, the modification is not inplace
print('First iteration:', len(df))
df = add_row(df)
print('Second iteration:', len(df))
df = add_row(df)
print('Third iteration:', len(df))
```

Output:

```
Original length: 0
First iteration: 1
Second iteration: 2
Third iteration: 3
```

Dataframe after 3 iterations:

```
>>> df
   time  mid_o  mid_h  mid_l  mid_c
0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Another way to append a row with `loc`:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = np.nan
print(df)

# Output
   time  mid_o  mid_h  mid_l  mid_c
0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know about the .loc option too.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to re-assign!

```
df = add_row(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).